# Finding an estimator for the variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

> Let $Y_1$~$Bin(n_1,p_1)$ and $Y_2$~$Bin(n_2,p_2)$ independent.
> Prove that $A:=Y_1(n_1-Y_1)/{n_1}^3+Y_2(n_2-Y_2)/{n_2}^3$ can be used as an estimator for the variance of $B:=Y_1/n_1-Y_2/n_2$.

I understand that I have to prove that $E(A)=Var(B)$.
Now, I have already calculated that the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}-\frac{Y_2}{n_2} = \frac{p_1(1-p1)}{n_1}+\frac{p_2(1-p2)}{n_2}$. But I tried calculating $E(A)$ and this is what I got:
$$E(Y_1(n_1-Y_1)/{n_1}^3+Y_2(n_2-Y_2)/{n_2}^3)=E(Y_1(n_1-Y_1)/{n_1}^3)+E(Y_2(n_2-Y_2)/{n_2}^3)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n_1^3}E(Y_1(n_1-Y_1))+\frac{1}{n_2^3}E(Y_2(n_2-Y_2))$$
$$=\frac{1}{n_1^3}n_1E(Y_1)-E({Y_1}^2)+\frac{1}{n_2^3}n_2E(Y_2)-E({Y_2}^2)$$
$$=\frac{{n_1}^2p_1-n_1p_1(1-p_1)-{n_1}^2{p_1}^2}{{n_1}^3}+\frac{{n_2}^2p_2-n_2p_2(1-p_2)-{n_2}^2{p_2}^2}{{n_2}^3}$$

Which does not appear to be equal to $Var(B)$. So, any help, suggestion or ideas are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: As @RoverPython answered, this problem is just requiring why we can use $A$ as an estimator for $Var(B)$ not unbiased estimator. There can be lots of estimators for a certain random variable. To get the best estimator, we seek unbiased estimator, UMVUE ... and so on. For instance, you can use divide by $n$ rather than $n-1$ when calculating sample variance. It can be an estimate, however much weaker than others.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method-of-moments estimator of variance using $\mathbb E[Y_i]=n_ip_i$, rather than an unbiased estimator of variance.

- The variance of $Y_1$ is $n_1p_1(1-p_1)$ and the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}$ is $\frac1{n_1} p_1(1-p_1)$
- The variance of $Y_2$ is $n_2p_2(1-p_2)$ and the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}$ is $\frac1{n_2} p_2(1-p_2)$
- Since they are independent, the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}-\frac{Y_2}{n_2}$ is
  $\frac1{n_1} p_1(1-p_1)+\frac1{n_2} p_2(1-p_2)$
- $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}$ is the natural estimator of $p_1$ and $\frac{Y_2}{n_2}$ is the natural estimator of $p_2$
- so *an* estimator of the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}-\frac{Y_2}{n_2}$ is $\frac1{n_1} \frac{Y_1}{n_1}\left(1-\frac{Y_1}{n_1}\right)+\frac1{n_2} \frac{Y_2}{n_2}\left(1-\frac{Y_2}{n_2}\right)$ $= \frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_1^3} +\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_2^3}$

---

This is not an unbiased estimator: $\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_1^2(n_1-1)} +\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_2^2(n_2-1)}$ would be an unbiased estimator of variance though with a larger root-mean-square error against the actual variance, illustrating that unbiasedness is not necessarily better.

As an example, suppose $n_1=2, p_1=1/3, n_2=3, p_2=1/4$.  Then the expectation of $\frac{Y_1}{n_1}-\frac{Y_2}{n_2}$ is $\frac{1}{12}\approx 0.0833$ and its variance is $\frac{25}{144} \approx 0.1736$.  We would like our estimator of the variance to be close to $\frac{25}{144}$ in some sense.

- The variance estimator $\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_1^3} +\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_2^3}$ has an expectation of $\frac{14}{144} \approx 0.0972$ so is biased downwards, with a root-mean-square error of $\frac{\sqrt{229}}{144}\approx 0.1051$
- The variance estimator $\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_1^2(n_1-1)} +\frac{Y_1(n_1-Y_1)}{n_2^2(n_2-1)}$ has an expectation of $\frac{25}{144} \approx 0.1736$ so is unbiased, with a root-mean-square error  of $\frac{\sqrt{383}}{144}\approx 0.1359$ so likely to be more wrong then the other estimator

This is an illustration of the bias-variance trade-off where some biased estimators can be more accurate on average.

Answer (score 0):

The Goal isn't to prove equivalence of the moments. You can see that you can just plug $n_1 p_1$ in place of $Y_1$, and $n_2 p_2$ in place of $Y_2$, and the result is the variance you estimate, even if the expected value is not equal to it.
An estimator doesn't always have the expected value of what should be estimated. Sometimes, you do this plug-in even if it doesn't translate into unbiasedness. What you usually want more is the estimator getting better with a bigger sample size, which holds for this method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).